# counting HTTP packets

Tags: http, packet

What is relation between number of HTTP packets and number of objects in a web page?

Comment: What's an "HTTP packet"? Requests, perhaps.

Comment: @above comments, based on what he said in PEdroArthur's response, I think he did not mean the number of packets, but rather, the number of HTTP requests

Answer (score 5):

> What is relation between number of HTTP packets and number of objects in a web page?

The short answer is there is obviously some relation, but there is no way you can accurately predict one from the other.

For a longer answer, we first need to correct some misconceptions in the question:

- There is no such thing as an "HTTP packet".  HTTP is a message oriented application protocol with one request message and one response message per "resource" fetched).  This sits on top of a reliable byte stream protocol (with flow control, etc) called TCP.  This in turn sits on top of a packet switching protocol called IP.  An HTTP request/response exchange takes an unpredictable number of IP packets ... depending on message sizes AND network conditions.  Other HTTP features such as compression, keeping connections alive, caching and so on make things even more complicated.
- The idea of an "object" is ill-defined.  An "object" could have a one-to-one correspondence between HTTP request / response pairs (i.e. a "resource" in the above) then that part is simple.  OTOH, a "resource" could be a rendering of multiple "objects" in the application domain of the webserver.
- On top of that, you've also got to account for the fact that a typical HTML resource has references to other resources (Scripts, CSS, images, etc) and may even involve Ajax callbacks.  Each of these is a "resource", that may or may not need to be fetched ... depending on caching, etc.
- Finally, there is an implicit assumption that all "objects" are the same size.  This might be true in some application domains, but it is not true in general.

So to summarize, there are far to many variables and unknowns for it to be feasible to predict the number of network packets required to fetch a certain number of "objects".

A more practical approach is to attach a packet-level network analyser to your network and get it to count the number of packets sent and received.

---

If you make the following assumptions:

- "HTTP packets" are HTTP messages,
- "objects" are resources,
- a resource doesn't require other resources (Scripts, CSS, images, etc) to render,
- there is no caching,
- the server is not doing redirects.

then one "object" requires two "HTTP packets".

But frankly, you've simplified the problem to a point where the answer is next to useless for predicting actual performance of real web-servers.  (For instance, any one of those "objects" could be tiny ... or huge.  And if you allow for arbitrary javascript, or content such as links to video streams, then the number of "packets" of one kind or another is potentially unbounded.)

Comment: I am aligned with your argues. However I disagree with you in the sense that such a simplification, along with the resources (average) sizes, may be used to render a upper bound for the demands of an application. It isn't the best metric to have, since predictions may lead to over spendings, but saves a lot o time in big network scenarios. And, with some experience, your brain creates a fine heuristic for it =D

Comment: The problem is that the result is not always an upper bound (e.g. referenced resources) and not always an indicative; e.g. an upper bound of $1,000,000 on a litre of milk is correct, but not indicative of how much my breakfast will cost.  You are correct about experience ... but the experience cannot be captured in a formula.

Comment: Indeed. However, this will never raise to such an exaggerated upper bound. Using my street fighting mathematics, I think that it would be only some times greater than the average (10x at maximum?), also providing a margin for crowds. However, my point is: this simplification is not optimal in the sense that it fails to gather all the variables involved (and maybe this problem can't be precisely formulated), but it isn't completely useless.

Comment: Furthermore, combined with some other analytical tool, like MVA and Markov chains, it can provide a nice prediction scenario, mainly when you don't have access to server logs or other source of sample data. Always remembering that ones must be careful and rational about these predictions.

Answer (score 2):

A GET request is issued for every file referred in a HTML page, all of which, usually, fit in one TCP stream segment. HTTP is a state machine, so, many requests/response can be pipelined in one request/response.

The number of packets sent in response vary in the size of the objects and in caching parameters. For example, if a file is already in the browser cache, it will make a conditional get and will receive a HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified response code, which does not contain any data. Moreover, many HTTP/1.1 304 can be issued in one segment, as this response is very tiny compared to segments' maximum size. Another example, if a file is bigger than the maximum segment size, the file may (and it probably will) be divided in many segments.

Is this what you wish to know?

Comment: Actually I want to consider simple condition no caching no history and totally simple page with some picture and javascript,css .... I want to know that Can I use number of HTTP requests as number of objects?

Comment: Yes, you can. Straightly, it's one GET request for the HTTP itself, plus one request for every file it refers to. Then, as sad @Mike, an asymptotic upper bound for the number of request in O(n).

Comment: Given that javascript can issue its own requests, the worst case number of requests (following the initial page load sequence) is infinite.  It depends on your definition of a "totally simple" web page ...